# perl, removing elements from array in for loop

Tags: arrays, perl, iteration, data-manipulation

will the following code always work in perl ?

```
for loop iterating over @array {
  # do something
  if ($condition) {
     remove current element from @array
  }
}
```

Because I know in Java this results in some Exceptions, The above code is working for me for now, but I want to be sure that it will work for all cases in perl. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, it's said in the [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements):

> If any part of LIST is an array, foreach will get very confused if you
>   add or remove elements within the loop body, for example with splice.
>   So don't do that.

It's a bit better with [each](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html):

> If you add or delete a hash's elements while iterating over it,
>   entries may be skipped or duplicated--so don't do that. Exception: In
>   the current implementation, *it is always safe to delete the item most
>   recently returned by each()*, so the following code works properly:

```
 while (($key, $value) = each %hash) {
    print $key, "\n";
    delete $hash{$key}; # This is safe
  }
```

But I suppose the best option here would be just using [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
@some_array = grep {
  # do something with $_
  some_condition($_);
} @some_array;
```

Comment: Right, the doc says not to remove/add elements in foreach loop, but what about the C-style for loop : for (my $i=0; $i<@array; $i++) ?

Comment: Ah, that's another story. This should be safe, as you basically just calculate the array's length each time when `for` is checking the exit condition.

Comment: Quick note... the `grep` example last line should be changed to remove the `return`. The last line of the inline sub is used as the conditional to determine if it should be included or not. (`return` gives a syntax error)