# splice doesnt work well in loop in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to understand splice.
I want to remove all the elements in array one by one using splice. But still the output i get is weird. I am not able to understand it. Could somebody please explain:

**Code**

```
my @arr1=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

foreach my $num(@arr1)
{
    print $_ foreach (@arr1);
    print "\n Popping $num\n";
    print "[0] is $arr1[0] and current element is $num \n";
    splice @arr1,0,1;
    print "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
 12345678910
 Popping 1
[0] is 1 and current element is 1

2345678910
 Popping 3
[0] is 2 and current element is 3

345678910
 Popping 5
[0] is 3 and current element is 5

45678910
 Popping 7
[0] is 4 and current element is 7

5678910
 Popping 9
[0] is 5 and current element is 9
```

Comment: Why not use `pop` or `shift` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [perl, removing elements from array in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895001/perl-removing-elements-from-array-in-for-loop)

Comment: The operation you're performing is called a `shift` in Perl; `pop` would be `splice(@arr1, -1)`. Also, `print` is a list operator, so `print $_ foreach (@arr1)` could be written more simply as `print @arr1`.

Comment: You can use `while ($_ = shift @array){print $_}` to remove elements of an array one by one.

Comment: @slade:well this question was simplified to pin point the issue I am facing in original prob. In my original problem I am deciding based on some logiv whether to remove the element or not. So its not always [0] that I want to remove. And imo shift would always remove 0th element only right?

Comment: Perl documentation page [perlsyn](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops) states: "foreach will get very confused if you add or remove elements within the loop body, for example with splice. So don't do that."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are changing the array whilst looping through it. the foreach goes form [0] to [1] to [2]. when you have spliced the [0], it goes to [1] which was the original [2]. when you have spliced that, it goes to [2] which now is the original [4] since you have taken the first ones away.

hope that clears it up a little.

you can avoid using @arr1 as the loop controller:

```
my @arr1=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

my $max = @arr1;
for (my $i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    print $_ foreach (@arr1);
    my $num = splice @arr1,0,1;
    print "\n Popping $num\n";
    print "[0] is $arr1[0] and current element is $num \n";
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: By the way , if I am making changes before foreach gets new element in context ,shouldnt it update the array and then consider it?

Comment: i am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

The [foreach](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) creates a list of the original 10 array elements.  You should use a `while` to modify an array.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @arr1=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

while (@arr1)
{
    my $num = $arr1[0];
    print $_ foreach (@arr1);
    print "\n Popping $num\n";
    print "[0] is $arr1[0] and current element is $num \n";
    splice @arr1,0,1;
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: `while` is just testing the array to see if it's empty.  The `splice` is what's consuming the elements.

Answer (score 2):

Don't modify the array over which you are iterating using foreach.

Often, The solution is usually `grep`. For example, the following processes the elements in `@todo`, leaving the ones that were unsuccessfully processed in the array.

```
sub process {
   ...
   return 0 if error;
   ...
   return 1;
}

@todo = grep { !process($_) } @todo;
```

In this case, replace `foreach` with `while`.

```
my @queue = 1..10;

while (@queue) {
   my $num = shift(@queue);
   print "Current element is $num\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 for grep, comments suggest this is what the op needs

Comment: @RobEarl, Added an example