# Perl array : Pattern matches then move to the another array

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, hash

Perl : I want to move each element of array which matches the pattern.

For example, I have below array
@array1 = {cat 2, dog 3#move, tiger 4#move, lion 10}

Now I want to move dog 3, tiger 4 (as pattern #move matches)  to another array lets say @array2

```
foreach $array (@array1) {
    if ($array =~ m/(./w*) (./d*)#move/) {
          push @array2, $1.$2;
    }
```

But I want to delete those elements from array1. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your pattern contains only one capture group, so it's unclear what `$2` is expected to be.

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what `@array1` contains? It is not the correct way to instantiate a Perl array, and the regex you provide would not match since there's no comma before `#move`. (and a word character is `\w`, not `/w`)

Comment: updated the array and regex, thanks for point it out

Answer (score 4):

There is more than one way to do it, so here's another one, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16895118/2877364): Use `grep` to keep the elements you want.  Since Perl only supports deleting elements from the array you're iterating over in certain situations, this does not require you to know which situations those are :) .

```
use strict; use warnings;
my @array1 = ("cat 2", "dog 3#move", "tiger 4#move", "lion 10");
my @array2;

@array1 = grep {    # We are going to search over @array1 and only keep some elements.
    if (/(.*)#move/) {  # If this is one we want to move...
        push @array2, $1;   # ... save it in array2...
        0;      # ... and do not keep it in array1.
    } else {
        1;      # Otherwise, do keep it in array1.
    }
} @array1;

# Debug output - not required
print "Array 1\n";
print join "\n", @array1;
print "\nArray 2\n";
print join "\n", @array2;
print "\n";
```

Output:

```
Array 1
cat 2
lion 10
Array 2
dog 3
tiger 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my @array1 = ("cat 2", "dog 3#move", "tiger 4#move", "lion 10");
my @array2;
my @temp;
for my $elem (@array1) {
    if ( $elem =~ m/^(.*)#move/) {
        push @array2, $1;
    }
    else {
        push @temp, $elem;
    }
}
@array1 = @temp;

p \@array1;
p \@array2;
```

**Output**:

```
[
    [0] "cat 2",
    [1] "lion 10"
]
[
    [0] "dog 3",
    [1] "tiger 4"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the extract_by function from [List::UtilsBy](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) does:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::UtilsBy 'extract_by';
my @array1 = ("cat 2", "dog 3#move", "tiger 4#move", "lion 10");
my @array2 = map { s/#move//r } extract_by { m/#move/ } @array1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using List::Util

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::Util qw(pairs pairgrep pairkeys);


my @array1 = ("cat 2", "dog 3#move", "tiger 4#move", "lion 10");

my $i=0;
my @indexList= map { ($i++, $_) } @array1;                     #build kv pairs

my @removed;
my @filtered=pairgrep { ($b =~ /#move/);} @indexList;          #grep kv pairs
push @removed, splice @array1, $_, 1 for (pairkeys @filtered); #splice and push

print "Modified original: @array1\n";
print "Removed elements: @removed\n";
```