# Issue with splicing of an element in the outermost "for" loop

Tags: perl

**Purpose:**
Intent of the script is to remove all the common elements in `difList` and `refList` and let the other-elements that are NOT common to both left as is. Script is expected to remove "Apple" "Banana" and "Grapes" from both `difList` and `refList`

**Issue:**
As you could see in the output, "Banana" though common to both `difList` and `refList`, it is NOT removed and still exists in both the lists.

**Reason:**
I thought, once you `splice` an element in the `difList` controlled by the outermost `for` loop, the array elements shift and hence do NOT match the internal incrementer. In this case once "Orange" removed, "Banana" took the place of "Orange" and the outer `for` loop incrementer already passed element[0] and hence "Banana" is missed. So "Banana" though common to both `difList` and `refList`, it is NOT removed.

But looking at the difIndex, it hit "Grapes" in the third iteration (difIndex is 2), indicating all the elements of `difList` are intact, inspite of splicing.

There is NO way resetting the outermost `for` loop incrementer to start from 0 whenever there is a `splice`.

**Question:**
Why is "Banana" being missed ? Is there an elegant way of achieving what I intend to do, without maintaining 2 separate  `difList` - (1) for processing and (2) other for `splicing` ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;

# Clean-up
my $refItem;
my $difItem;
my $refIndex = 0;
my $difIndex = 0;
my @refList = ("Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Grapes", "Oranges", "BlueBerries");
my @difList = ("Oranges", "Banana", "StrawBerries", "Grapes");

$difIndex = 0;
foreach $difItem (@difList) {
    $refIndex = 0;
    foreach $refItem (@refList) {
        if ($difItem eq $refItem) {
            print "EQUAL: difIndex: $difIndex difItem: $difItem refIndex: $refIndex refItem: $refItem\n";
            splice(@refList, $refIndex, 1);
            splice(@difList, $difIndex, 1);
            last;
        } 
        $refIndex++;
    }
    $difIndex++;
}

print "-----------------------\n";
for (@difList) {
    print "FINAL: difList: $_\n"
}
print "-----------------------\n"; 
for (@refList) {
    print "FINAL: refList: $_\n"
}
```

Output of the code is below

```
    EQUAL: difIndex: 0 difItem: Oranges refIndex: 4 refItem: Oranges
    EQUAL: difIndex: 2 difItem: Grapes refIndex: 3 refItem: Grapes
    -----------------------
    FINAL: difList: Banana
    FINAL: difList: StrawBerries
    -----------------------
    FINAL: refList: Apple
    FINAL: refList: Banana
    FINAL: refList: Pear
    FINAL: refList: BlueBerries
```

Comment: Modifying an element in place is probably okay but it's safer not to try to alter the size of an array that you are iterating over. Your algorithm seems to be O(m*n). You can solve in O(m+n) with a hash: `%ct=(); for(@difList,@refList){$ct{$_}++} @difList=grep{$ct{$_}==1}@difList; @refList=grep{$ct{$_}==1}@refList;`

Comment: cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16895118/10971581

Comment: 1) You can't modify the array overwhich you are iterating. 2) This approach performs horribly: O(N*M) vs O(N+M)

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply find the differences and overwrite the original arrays?

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @ary1 = qw(a b 2 3);
my @ary2 = qw(A B 2 3);

my %a1 = map { $_ => 1 } @ary1;
my @two_only = grep { not $a1{$_} } @ary2;

my %a2 = map { $_ => 1 } @ary2;
my @one_only = grep { not $a2{$_} } @ary1;

@ary1 = @one_only;
@ary2 = @two_only;

say "Only in one: @ary1";
say "Only in two: @ary2";
```

To literally just change arrays so to contain their unique elements need only

```
my %a1 = map { $_ => 1 } @ary1;
my %a2 = map { $_ => 1 } @ary2;

@ary2 = grep { not $a1{$_} } @ary2;
@ary1 = grep { not $a2{$_} } @ary1;
```

Note that this does not deal with the pesky question of what to do with duplicates, if there are any, since that depends on what is wanted.

There are libraries for comparing arrays, like [List::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare).<sup>†</sup>

---

Changing arrays while they are being iterated over is very tricky, at best; just a bad idea really. I can't now go through it to find the error but it may well be along the lines of your analysis.

---

<sup>†</sup>  See also [Algorithm::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Diff), which offers different (while related) tools

Answer (score 0):

Your method confused me, so I worked from scratch.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @refList = ("Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Grapes", "Oranges", "BlueBerries");
my @difList = ("Oranges", "Banana", "StrawBerries", "Grapes");

my %count;

# Count the occurrences across both arrays
++$count{$_} for @refList, @difList;

# Delete keys where the count is 1.
# You're then left with the difference between the two arrays.
for (keys %count) {
  delete $count{$_} if $count{$_} == 1;
}

# Use grep on both arrays to keep only elements that aren't
# found as keys in %count
@refList = grep { ! $count{$_} } @refList;
@difList = grep { ! $count{$_} } @difList;

say "@refList";
say "@difList";
```

Comment: if you just `...grep{$count{$_}==1}...` directly you don't need the delete pass, so you only scan the arrays twice instead of three times

Comment: Note that this solution assumes that both `@refList` and `@difList` only contain only unique elements. A simpler solution is possible with this assumption: `my %keep; ++$keep{$_} for @refList; --$keep{$_} for @difList; @refList = grep $keep{$_}, @refList; @difList = grep $keep{$_}, @difList;`